# UITableViewCell bottom margin constraint

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I have the following `UITableViewCell` , where based on a condition, the `redView.heightConstraint.constant = 0` , this works fine.

But the the bottom space turns out to be a+b = **20**, where

```
a = 10   between green an red view
b = 10   between red and bottom of the superview
```

The expected bottom space , when height of the redView is set to 0 should be **10.**  How should I set the constraint to achieve the expected bottom margin of 10, when redView height is set to 0 ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a vertical spacing constraint between the red and green views? Have you tried setting it to 0 as well, when you set the red view's height to 0? Or you could try setting the red view's bottom space constraint to 0 when you adjust the height.

Comment: I can create a outlet for it. But I will have to set the value to 10 if the condition satisfies or 0 if it does not. But For that I would have to declare a constant and set to value to 10. But was looking for a more dynamic approach.

Comment: Yeah, I always find changing constraints to be a bit clunky. I'm not sure there's a better way to do it :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the height of that red view does not change its position with regards to to bottom of the superview, so that the green view has first a `10 pix` margin to the top of that view, and an additional `10 pix` to the bottom of the superview.

#### Option 1: Change 2 constraints

1. `redView.heightConstraint.constant = 0`
2. `redView.bottomConstraint.constant = 0`

[image: 2 constraints must be changed]

Do these two changes together, and the red view will effectively become a zero height view at the bottom of its superview ; the green view will just follow suit.

#### Option 2: Embed the red view inside an invisible placeholder

- `placeholder.heightConstraint.constant = 0`

[image: embedded view in placeholder]

The placeholder (gray rectangle) is anchored to the bottom of the superview ; it contains the red view and its vertical spacer. The blue view is no longer spaced with regards to the top of the red view but to the top of its placeholder. This solution involves less lines of code, traded for a slightly more complicated resource.

---

Either way, you may store the Storyboard resource `constant` when the view is first loaded to avoid hardcoding:

```
// At the class level
let originalHeight = someView.heightConstraint.constant

// At the method level, toggle
someView.heightConstraint.constant = (fullHeight) ? originalHeight : 0
```

Comment: Option 2 works well. As In option 1, I will have to set the  redView.bottomConstraint.constant = 0 when condition is true and redView.bottomConstraint.constant = CONSTANT when its false, this constant I will have to set from the code , so if I change the spacing in Storyboard from 10 to 12, I will have to update the same in the code.

Comment: You are correct: by introducing more code, you are introducing more complexity and possibly more bugs. In neither #1 or #2 would you need to hardcode though: you can read the resource `constant` height value on load, store it, and use it to restore

Comment: I prefer #2 as well because it has less code, so fewer places to break. I added a note on how to not hardcode `constant`.

Comment: Thats a good note. I was thinking to create a var and initialize that constant in awake from nib.  But  its Good point to add it at class level.